# Is there a way to use super() to call the __init__ method of each base class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, inheritance, super

Let's suppose I have a bit of Python code:

```
class Mother:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Mother")

class Father:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Father")

class Daughter(Mother, Father):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Daughter")
        super().__init__()

d = Daughter()
```

This script prints "Daughter". Is there anyway to ensure that all of the __init__ methods of the bases classes are called? One method I came up with to do this was:

```
class Daughter(Mother, Father):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Daughter")
        for base in type(self).__bases__:
            base.__init__(self)
```

This script prints "Daughter", "Mother", "Father". Is there a nice way to do this using super() or another method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raymond Hettinger explained this really well in his talk [Super Considered Super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) from PyCon 2015.  The short answer is yes, if you design this way, and call `super().__init__()` in each class

```
class Mother:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Mother")

class Father:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Father")

class Daughter(Mother, Father):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Daughter")
```

The name `super` is unfortunate, it really works its way through the base classes.